# Is there a way to divide the keras mobilenetv2 model into submodels?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, mobilenet

I am trying to divide the `mobilenetv2` model into 2 parts.

I first want to run the first part of the model, save the output, and feed it later on to the second model for certain reasons. I've tried code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55914871/10402016),
but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.
```

I think it is because the model isn't a Sequential.
Can someone help?

Comment: Can you share the line where you try to merge two layers (i.e., the line causing the error)?

Comment: I think its when I add it, using following line:       `model_h.add(model.layers[current_layer])`. Thank you for the fast response.

Comment: If you used the code in the link you mentioned, it should work. I am assuming the problem lies where you are trying to split `mobilenetv2`. Not all Mobilenet layers are sequential, and not all of them take the output of a single layer as input. Some layers take outputs of multiple layers and merge them. Make sure you split your mobilenetv2 in such a way that the second part expects a single layer's output as input, not multiple. Without seeing your code, that is all my assumptions right now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. May I ask at which layer I can split, and how you can see to split at that layer? [Here is the link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17IgAkO8cO--du4xNsdn9tJ_DZK84_4Xl) to the google colab file.Thank you in advance Bashir!

Comment: Okay so I can split it until layer block_2_add (layer 27, see colab notebook). This is the first layer connected to multiple layers. I can't split anymore after this layer. Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments, some layers in mobile_net_v2 expect more than one inputs which are outputs of some other previous layers. Therefore adding them to a *sequential* model individually causes errors. I have an alternative solution for you. Using the mobile_net_v2 implementation (of my own) in [this](https://github.com/Bashirkazimi/BashirLearning/blob/master/src/mobile_net_v2.py) link, I was able to create the models you want:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, Sequential


def conv_block(input_tensor, c, s, t, expand=True):
    """
    Convolutional Block for mobile net v2
    Args:
        input_tensor (keras tensor): input tensor
        c (int): output channels
        s (int): stride size of first layer in the series
        t (int): expansion factor
        expand (bool): expand filters or not?

    Returns: keras tensor
    """
    first_conv_channels = input_tensor.get_shape()[-1]
    if expand:
        x = layers.Conv2D(
            first_conv_channels*t,
            1,
            1,
            padding='same',
            use_bias=False
        )(input_tensor)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = layers.ReLU(6.0)(x)
    else:
        x = input_tensor

    x = layers.DepthwiseConv2D(
        3,
        s,
        'same',
        1,
        use_bias=False
    )(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.ReLU(6.0)(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(
        c,
        1,
        1,
        padding='same',
        use_bias=False
    )(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    if input_tensor.get_shape() == x.get_shape() and s == 1:
        return x+input_tensor

    return x


def splitted_model(input_shape=(224,224,3)):

    input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

    x = layers.Conv2D(
        32,
        3,
        2,
        padding='same',
        use_bias=False
    )(input)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.ReLU(6.0)(x)

    x = conv_block(x, 16, 1, 1, expand=False)
    x = conv_block(x, 24, 2, 6)
    x = conv_block(x, 24, 1, 6)

    x = conv_block(x, 32, 2, 6)
    x = conv_block(x, 32, 1, 6)
    x = conv_block(x, 32, 1, 6)

    x = conv_block(x, 64, 2, 6)
    x = conv_block(x, 64, 1, 6)
    x = conv_block(x, 64, 1, 6)
    x = conv_block(x, 64, 1, 6)

    model_f = Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)

    input_2 = layers.Input(shape=(x.shape[1:]))
    x = conv_block(input_2, 96, 1, 6)
    x = conv_block(x, 96, 1, 6)
    x = conv_block(x, 96, 1, 6)

    x = conv_block(x, 160, 2, 6)
    x = conv_block(x, 160, 1, 6)
    x = conv_block(x, 160, 1, 6)

    x = conv_block(x, 320, 1, 6)

    x = layers.Conv2D(
        1280,
        1,
        1,
        padding='same',
        use_bias=False
    )(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.ReLU(6.0)(x)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)


    model_h = Model(inputs=input_2, outputs=x)

    return model_f, model_h
```

You could create your two models as such:

```
IMG_SIZE = 160
IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
model_f, model_h = splitted_model(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE)
```

Note that the weights are randomly initialized. If you want to have the weights from mobilenet_v2 trained on *imagenet*, you could run the following code to copy weights:

```
mobile_net = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                           include_top=False,
                                           weights='imagenet')
layer_f_counter = 0
layer_h_counter = 0
for i in range(len(mobile_net.layers)):
  if layer_f_counter<len(model_f.layers):
    if len(mobile_net.layers[i].get_weights()) > 0:
      if len(model_f.layers[layer_f_counter].get_weights()) > 0:
        print(mobile_net.layers[i].name,'here', model_f.layers[layer_f_counter].name, layer_f_counter)
        model_f.layers[layer_f_counter].set_weights(mobile_net.layers[i].get_weights())
      layer_f_counter += 1
      print(layer_f_counter)
    else:
      if len(model_f.layers[layer_f_counter].get_weights()) > 0:
        continue
      else:
        layer_f_counter+=1

  else:
    if layer_h_counter<len(model_h.layers):
      if len(mobile_net.layers[i].get_weights()) > 0:
        if len(model_h.layers[layer_h_counter].get_weights()) > 0:
          print(mobile_net.layers[i].name,'here', model_h.layers[layer_h_counter].name, layer_h_counter)
          model_h.layers[layer_h_counter].set_weights(mobile_net.layers[i].get_weights())
        layer_h_counter += 1
        print(layer_h_counter)
      else:
        if len(model_h.layers[layer_h_counter].get_weights()) > 0:
          continue
        else:
          layer_h_counter+=1
```

It iterates through the layers of *mobilenet_v2* loaded from *Keras*, it copies the weights of the first part to *model_f*, and the rest to *model_h*. You could check that the weights are correctly copied by print out some random layer weights from mobile_net and also the new models as follows:

```
print(model_f.layers[1].get_weights()) # printing weights of first conv layer in model_f
print(mobile_net.get_layer('Conv1').get_weights()) # printing weights of fist conv layer in mobile_net
```

Also for model_h:

```
print(model_h.layers[-4].get_weights()) # printing weights of last conv layer in model_h
print(mobile_net.get_layer('Conv_1').get_weights()) # printing weights of last conv layer in mobile_net
```

Note that I randomly selected which block to separate moile_net into model_f and model_h, you could edit it to change where you want to split. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it later!

Comment: Is it possible that I get more wrong predictions in comparison with the original model?

Comment: Do I need to compile the models? Because I have the problem of getting the same prediction for every input? I do a prediction with the first one and use the output as input of the second one. I also added a dense and softmax layer because my original model has it too.

Comment: You do not need to compile if you use the layers copied from the trained mobile_net model, but if you added a dense layer, it has randomly initialised weights and hence you have to compile and train.

Comment: Yes I have a model with a mobilenet base model, I added a dense layer, trained the model and saved it. Then I import this model and load in the weights using the code you posted. I also added the dense layer in the splitted_model function but still get wrong predictions. Am I doing something wrong because the weights of the dense layer are also loaded in? PS trained with base model: `tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet'),classes=2)`

Comment: I'm not really sure anymore, sorry.